# Sims 4 pop radio, what song?

Tags: the-sims-4, game-music-identification

Right now my sims are listening to the pop radio, and a song came on which I really like. I have tried looking up lists with songs which are on the pop radio, but I can't find this one. Does anyone have an idea?

It's pretty slow and I feel like it's a guy singing it (In simlish of course) 'Moeda of toeeeeeee' just a random quote I just heard (It sounded like that, I'm sure it said something different. But there are quite some words that end in like, a long way like i wrote 'toe'. I hope this makes sense lol.

Comment: If you go into the settings, you can customize your radio. It lists all of the songs by name, so you can toggle them. You should be able to find your song there.